# does the phrase"as to be offensive" refer to "so contrary"?

Tags: comparative-constructions

> I am reminded of a Yiddish saying:
>
> > If hard work was so wonderful, the rich would have kept it all for themselves
>
> It’s true that many wealthy people work long hours. But to imply that poor people need to “work harder” is **so contrary to the facts as to be offensive**.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're asking? It helps if you mark quotes (what you're trying to understand) using the quote markup by adding a > before that content.

Comment: @Catija - I think the entire question is in the title, and the entire body of the question is a quote. That, at any rate, is how I'm editing it.

Comment: The idiom here is: to be so [adjective] as to be [another adjective]. And it means: x is so y that it is y.

Answer (score 3):

*as to be offensive* is the complement of *so*.

How contrary to the facts is this implication? —It is so contrary to the fact as to be offensive.

The construction *so X as to VERB* is equivalent to *so X that it VERBs*.

Your author is saying that to imply that poor people need to work harder is not only a rhetorical exaggeration, the implication distorts the fact to such a degree that it is downright offensive.

Answer (score 1):

to be so fat as to be enormous

to be so wealthy as to be disgusting

to be so stupid as to be mentally challenged

to be so [adjective] as to be [some other adjective or noun]